# Imprimir un solo nodo

Tags: c++

Tengo una lista enlazada donde cada nodo contiene información de un equipo de computo es decir marca, procesador etc
quedando algo asi:

Nodo1:Marca,procesador,color.

Nodo2.Marca procesador, color.

```
struct nodo{
              string marca;
              string procesador;
              struct nodo *sgte;
};

void insertar(Milista &lista, string marca, String procesador)
{

    Milista q;
    q = new(struct nodo);
    q->marca=marca;
    q->procesador procesador;
    q->sgte = lista;
    lista  = q;
}
```

y tengo mi funcion que la imprime

```
void reportarLista(Milista lista)
{
     int i = 0;

     while(lista != NULL)
     {
          cout << lista->marca << lista->procesador << endl;
          lista = lista->sgte;
          i++;
     }
}
```

Hay alguna manera de imprimir un nodo en especifico, me refiero a algo parecido como cuando imprimes un arreglo en tal posición, es decir imprimir parcialmente la lista.

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

En ReportarLista podrias agregar otro argumento que sea el nombre de la marca que buscas, entonces en el while haces un if para comparar la Marca del nodo **actual** con el nombre de la marca que pasaste como argumento, si es igual lo imprimis, fuera del if le pones el lista=lista->stge

```
void reportarLista(Milista lista, string nomMarca){
   while(lista!=NULL){
      if (lista->marca==nomMarca){
         cout<<lista->marca<<lista->procesador<<endl;
      lista=lista->sgte;
}
```